Is it guaranteed that tasks in DispatchQueue or OperationQueue will complete when switching back to the app later, assuming the app was not terminated
Is there a chance that tasks queued (eg. DispatchQueue.global()) but not yet start could be discarded, even if the app hasn’t been terminated, after switching to another app or locking the screen for a while?

In order to experience this situation, you need a sufficiently long running non-suspending task, which is longer than the app is in background before it gets suspended. This is roughly a few seconds, but it's not a hard number because it depends on several other factors. I would guess, when an app is suspended - but not terminated, and gets back to foreground it will just proceed where it stopped. You may test this yourself. ;)

The problem with this question is that it equivocates on the word "background". A DispatchQueue or OperationQueue can be used to run a task on a background thread (i.e. not on the main thread). This has nothing to do with the backgrounding of the app and what happens to your code in that situation. You may want code to run when the app is backgrounded, but that has nothing to do with "background tasks" in the sense of what kind of thread the code runs on.

There is still too much hand-waving in the question. "queued but not yet completed" makes no sense, because "queued" implies that the task is not yet even started. But basically the answer to your question remains No. There would be hell to pay if the system could just throw away code it was in the middle of at suspension time. Core Animation animations are indeed stopped when the app is suspended, but that's not running code and it isn't due to code being discarded (it is due to the animation object itself being removed from its layer).

Still in all, I would urge you to experiment. It may be that your code is not sufficiently long-running for the issue to arise at all. Or if the issue does arise, you will immediately see what does in fact happen. Remember, programmers try stuff. Build yourself some test scenarios and try them out and see what actually happens. There is no need to ask about it.

"Is there a chance that tasks queued but not yet start could be discarded?" Yes. The rest of the qualifications do not matter. This is absolutely, always possible. The app may crash. The battery may run out. The device may be destroyed. It is always possible for a task to be discarded. If you say "but I don't mean in those cases" then you mean that you can recover from the task being discarded, in which case you can recover from the cases you're thinking of as well. When you say "is there a chance," do you mean "is it extremely common?"

@RobNapier, in a situation where we return to our app, we see it remains on the same screen. However, memory usage might be very high, we might stayed in the other app for a long time or others but we return to our app we see the same screen. There are a number of tasks queued up in DispatchQueue.global(). Is it possible that some tasks might get discarded, even if it's a extremely rare case.

@RobNapier, in what cases could we return to the app without the app being terminated, but still find that tasks in DispatchQueue.global() have been discarded.

What does "There are a number of tasks queued up in DispatchQueue.global()" mean? How do you determine this fact? (There is no way to query a queue's "contents.") The way you're describing it sounds like you're thinking .global() is a serial queue. It is a concurrent queue. Tasks do not run in order. I would expect the WorkItems you're describing have already completed or have been canceled. A WorkItem that is canceled before it is scheduled will never be scheduled. You really need to write a question here that addresses your actual problem and why you believe you have it.


I'm determining to use DispatchQueue, DispatchQueue.global() or OperationQueue to manage background tasks in my app.

GCD operations are not background tasks.
When you send an app to the background, all running (standard) operations are suspended almost instantly.
Consider the following simple example:
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    for step in 1...10 {
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)
        print("\(step)")
    }
}

print("Task completed")

For example, if you now send the app to the background after the output of “3”, the operation is immediately suspended.
When you start the app again, there are 2 scenarios:

The app has remained in memory and the OS wakes the app up again.
In this scenario, the process is continued at the interrupted point and “4” is output next, followed by the remaining outputs.

The OS has terminated the app and removed it from the memory.
In this case, the app starts fresh and the operation is never completed.  It is the app developer's responsibility to resume the operation if required. Apple describes one way to do this here.



In this scenario, is it guaranteed that all tasks in both DispatchQueue and OperationQueue will eventually complete when I return to the app?

There is no guarantee that an operation will be completed when an app is sent to the background. The OS can terminate apps that are in the background at any time.
If you have a task that needs to run in the background, you need to do this specifically by using background tasks or the beginBackgroundTask(withName:expirationHandler:) method.
The latter gives your operation a limited time to complete; if this time is exceeded, the operation is aborted.
I recommend reading the following article:
Choosing Background Strategies for Your App

Is there a chance in scenario 1 that, upon returning, the app hasn’t terminated, but 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10 no longer appear?

If you are doing everything right, then no - the process should always continue in scenario 1 from the point at which it was interrupted leading to "4,5,6,7,8,9,10" as an ouput. If you are familiar with the “Suspend to RAM” function of operating systems, you can compare scenario 1 it with this. The state of your process is frozen in memory and restored in a similar way. Note, however, that certain system APIs may react when an app is sent to the background and may explicitly abort its operation. However, this depends on the specific API and should be documented.

Code is not thrown away or discarded or ignored merely because the app goes into the background. If the app goes into the background, the running of its code may be suspended. But if the app then comes back to the foreground, the app's suspended code will be resumed. Why the app's code was running, or where (architecturally) it was running, makes no difference to this fact.
Nevertheless, it is generally not good practice to depend upon this. If you are initiating a piece of long-running code and you want to ensure that it runs to completion even if the app is backgrounded, best practice is to request extra running time in the background for that code. You have already been pointed to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623051-beginbackgroundtask which tells you how to do this.
(But there is no need to do this unless your code is long-running. Only experimentation will reveal what "long-running" means here. Be sure to test on a device, as the simulator is not subject to the same rigor. The grace period before suspension upon app backgrounding used to be 30 seconds but it has been years since I tested, so this number may have changed since then.)

There's no guarantee that all the tasks will be completed if your app goes into the background, especially due to system resource management.
Consider using background tasks to ensure the completion of critical tasks.
that is beginBackgroundTask(withName:expirationHandler:) method from UIApplication
It would help if you tried to test the app's behaviour when in the background so you can know which task runs to completion and which gets interrupted.
Although the first job will print "WillWork" and "ScheduleWork" right away according to the code provided, there is no assurance that "DidWork" will be printed once the application has been backgrounded, particularly if it is terminated or if resources are limited.

Even when I return to the app?

What David said was making sure that your app takes appropriate actions when backgrounded. You may get an additional event “you’ll be backgrounded and your processor stops running in a few seconds”. Apart from that, running tasks will be suspended, and will start running again when the app goes back to the foreground.
